# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 Developer Edition intellisense not working

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I installed Developer edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 and find out intellisense is not working or show as other developer talking about.

Is there anything else I need to do to get intellisense working in SQL Server Management Studio?

What I do to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you must be working with a SQL Server 2008+ instance, for the server to be able to give you the metadata for intellisense.

It is a fine art making intellisense work for you.

The first thing you can to do make it recognize the database context is to put

```
USE databasename;
```

at the top of your query window. This gives it a better grasp of where you are working.

The next thing you need to get used to is to write your queries in a different order, fill in the FROM clause first, so the skeleton should be something like

```
SELECT ^
FROM tblname
```

or

```
UPDATE tblname
SET ^
```

At the position marked `^`, intellisense will have a good idea of what db/table context you are working in.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.^
FROM tblname a, tbl2 b
```

Without fully specifying the join condition, just listing the tables as above allows intellisense to work with `a.`

There are many other tricks, such as if you renamed objects, you're best off to start a new query window or disconnect from the server completely and reconnect, or even restarts SSM Studio.

Other reading:

- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/using-intellisense-in-sql-server-2008/446
- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/

Comment: i still find it's not worked any other trick i can use for this.

Comment: @ankit are you even connected to a sql server 2008 instance? what does `select @@version` show?

Comment: i got Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) but not found anything why they not worked

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to "refresh" the intellisense cache.

> 3) IntelliSense should be refreshed
>   with the latest changes in database. 
>   a) Press CTRL+SHIFT+R b) Go to Edit >>
>   IntelliSense >> Refresh Local Cache

Full list of things to make sure of:

1. Connected to SQL Server **2008** edition
2. Intellisense enabled
3. Intellisense refreshed
4. Correct settings for "Statement completion"

Check  [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/31/sql-server-2008-intellisense-does-not-work-enable-intellisense/) for a complete instructions with screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

If you have recently installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1 you may be encountering a bug. Microsoft has [confirmed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/650569/ssms-2008-r2-is-losing-intellisense-after-installing-visual-studio-2010-sp1) that VS 2010 SP1 effectively breaks intellisense in SQL Management Studio.

Here are a couple of options you can try:

1. [DevArt's SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) -$0 free
2. RedGate's SQL Prompt - $195 <-You can find it at red-gate.com.

Comment: i not need devart product i know they are taking money by devart mysql product who have some feature who have no cost but devart charge from them from their user.how much shameful it is.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be talking to at least a 2008 server.